# How can I select only some specific Data when Using Last Row?

Tags: excel, vba

I would Like to only copy the information in Range A2:P13. This Data gets spit out In different rows from time to time, and some times additional data in some of the columns gets added. I wrote a script that allows me to Select and copy everything from the last row to an x number rows up. Problem is that this amount of rows can be variable And there is way more data above the shared image (its clutter). Is there a way to modify my script so it counts down to the last row and once it hits "n" or "Calibration" it selects 8 rows above it?
Thanks in advance :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfTcI.png)

```
Option Explicit
Sub Import_File()


    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim OpenBook As Workbook
    Dim myValue As Variant
    Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Last24Rows As Range


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    myValue = InputBox("Please Input Run Number")

    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*),*.xl*", , "Choose File", "Open", False)

    If FileToOpen = False Then
    Exit Sub

        Else

        Set OpenBook = Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
   
            Set Sht2 = OpenBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    End If

    lastRow = Sht2.Range("H" & Sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

Set Last4Rows = Sht2.Range("A" & lastRow - 4 & ":AZ" & lastRow)
Last4Rows.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(myValue).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
OpenBook.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I tried Including  this

```
' Dim wb As Workbook
 '       Dim ws As Worksheet
  '      Dim FoundCell As Range
   '     Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    '    Set ws = ActiveSheet
     '
      '      Const WHAT_TO_FIND As String = "Calibration"
'
 '           Set FoundCell = ws.Range("A:A").Find(What:=WHAT_TO_FIND)
  '          If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
   '             MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " found in row: " & FoundCell.Row)
    '        Else
     '           MsgBox (WHAT_TO_FIND & " not found")
      '      End If
```

But it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will select 8 rows above wherever it finds "calibration". The -8 makes it move up 8 rows, and then the resize(8) resizes it to include the 8 rows below. It will create an error if it can't find "calibration", it would be easy to change that to send a text box instead.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
 
 
 Dim found As Range
 Dim SelectionRange As Range
 Dim what_to_find As String
 Dim FoundRow As Long
 
 
 what_to_find = "calibration"
 
 
 Set found = Cells.Find(What:=what_to_find, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       

FoundRow = found.row

Set SelectionRange = Rows(FoundRow - 8).Resize(8)

SelectionRange.Select


  
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Please mark it as solved if your question is answered